# Is this a mango tree?

Tags: identification, trees, outdoor

This plant started growing in one of my outdoor pots. We’re in the Caribbean, and it’s growing in an outdoor concrete rooftop at 90+ degrees (with little shade) where only cacti survive.

Is it some type of fruit plant? A weed? It’s been growing for a quite a while: the whole plant with roots is almost 3-ft long and the leaves are almost a foot long.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a mango

Here is a picture of a mango leaf from the University of Wisconsin La Crosse.
[image]

> Tough Leaves
> Mango leaves are equipped with a thick outer cuticle to prevent water and nutrient loss.  Also, mango leaves are found alternating on the plant stem to maximize the light energy received from the sun.  This is due to the fact that mangos grow best in full sun.

Here is a mango sapling about the same size as yours
From an article titled "[What are the chances for this mango tree?](https://www.houzz.com/discussions/2182370/what-are-the-chances-for-this-mango-tree)"
[image]

It can be tricky to identify plants from pictures but this feels like a pretty good match